# Using exec-maven-plugin to a maven phase

Tags: maven, exec-maven-plugin

I am using the exec-maven-plugin to execute a java application to do some code generation in my project:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.codegenerator.CodeGeneratorApplication</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This works fine if I execute in command line "mvn exec:java", but now I want to attach this code generation to a maven phase "generate-resources", so I have changed the pom to:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>codegeneration</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals><goal>java</goal></goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.codegenerator.CodeGeneratorApplication</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But suddenly when I execute "mvn exec:java", i got errors like:

```
[09:52:03.926] [] [] [com.codegenerator.CodeGeneratorApplication.main()] [WARN ] [AbstractApplicationContext.java:550] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'codeGeneratorApplication': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'cnp.application.acronym' in value "${cnp.application.acronym}"
[09:52:03.940] [] [] [com.codegenerator.CodeGeneratorApplication.main()] [INFO ] [DirectJDKLog.java:179] - Stopping service Tomcat
[09:52:03.982] [] [] [com.codegenerator.CodeGeneratorApplication.main()] [INFO ] [AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer.java:101] - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[09:52:03.987] [] [] [com.codegenerator.CodeGeneratorApplication.main()] [ERROR] [SpringApplication.java:815] - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'codeGeneratorApplication': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'cnp.application.acronym' in value "${cnp.application.acronym}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
    at com.codegenerator.CodeGeneratorApplication.main(CodeGeneratorApplication.java:26)
```

Could someone help me what is wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 'configuration' element needs to be inside the 'execution' element.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>codegeneration</id>
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                <goals><goal>java</goal></goals>
                <configuration>
                   <mainClass>com.codegenerator.CodeGeneratorApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>

</plugin>
```